# CURL finish executing and timeout

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm performing a server request with curl in C++ which return responses in pieces and those pieces's size may also vary.

At the time of arrival of each piece, the callback function is being called. The problem is I can't detect when the connection finished in order to perform an another callback to my parent class.

And by the way, I want to know if we can set and detect timeout for a curl?

Here is my code in short:

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "My URL");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "My Postfields");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeCallback);

curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
curl_global_cleanup();
```

The default callback:

```
size_t writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
{
    //do something
    //But how can I detect the last callback when connection finished
    //in order to call an another one?
    return size*nmemb;
}
```

Comment: Um. How about saving off your data and doing your followup work *after* `curl_easy_perform` returns?

Comment: @WhozCraig: sorry my bad. I deleted my previous comment. Seem that you lead me to the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you want can be saved off during the callback, then used once `curl_easy_perform` returns. Example:

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

// NOTE: added to accumulate data.
std::string result;

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "My URL");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "My Postfields");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &result); // NOTE: added
curl_easy_perform(curl);

// TODO: do something with your data stored in result

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
curl_global_cleanup();
```

And in your write callback:

```
size_t writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
{
    std::string* pstr = static_cast<std::string*>(up);
    std::copy(buf, buf+size*nmemb, std::back_inserter(*pstr));
    return size*nmemb;
}
```

or something along those lines. I leave all the error checking to you (and sorry for any typos; I don't have a compiler to validate this on immediately available to me).

Regarding timeout length, there are a multitude of timeout options available to a easy-mode curl request. Too many to mention here, in fact. See the documentation for [**curl_easy_setopt**](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html), in particular the connection options approximately 2/3rd of the way down the page.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It solves the problem. The key here is CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, I didn't understand it well though.

Comment: @NhonNguyen its a generic pointer that curl will take you you as an option (obviously) and pass *back* to you as a piece of goo during a call to your write-callback. We used the address of a local `std::string` object, which we then dereference and append all the data we just received to it. When the curl operation is complete, any data we received will be back in our string.

Comment: I meant it was the CURLOPT_WRITEDATA that I didn't understand so that I got stuck. But when you gave me an example, I get it well! Thank you again for clarifying. It's very kind of you :)